# Decoding a NumPy floats array into a varied-length data blocks?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy floats array in the following format:

```
[sizeA,headerA,sizeA items,sizeB,headerB,sizeB items...sizeN,headerN,sizeN items]
```

Since I don't know in advance how many items I have for each block, I'm currently do the jump manually (iterate over the array, check the num value and skip to the next block accordingly) and fill the data blocks with data.
I'm sure that python has more sophisticated way to handle it without iterating over each item...

For example, 3 data blocks - one with two values, the second with 3 values and the last one with single value (remove the header parts for clarity)

Sample input:

```
[2.0,3.12345,0.9967,3.0,5.2345,0.345,0.023,1.0,4.2345]
```

I want to have an output dictionary looks like:

```
{'A':[3.12345,0.9967], 'B':[5.2345,0.345,0.023], 'C':[4.2345]}
```

Comment: can you show us your data format?

Comment: Just edit my question, hope the data format is clearer now

Comment: How are the sizes encoded? As floats? And do you know the header lengths?

Comment: Can you give examples of the input and desired output? At the moment, it's not clear what your input looks like (what's its Python type, for example), or what sort of output you're looking for (a 1d NumPy array? a 2d NumPy array? A list of arrays?). An example would clear that up.

Comment: Thanks @MarkDickinson, I've added the missing info

Answer (score 1):

This works, but may not be the simplest solution:

```
a=[2.0,3.12345,0.9967,3.0,5.2345,0.345,0.023,1.0,4.2345]

keys=[a[0]] # list of the sizes
values=[]
i=[0]
while True:
    i.append(int(sum(keys))+len(keys))
    if i[-1]<len(a):
        keys.append(a[i[-1]])
    else:
        break

values=[a[i[j]+1:i[j+1]] for j in range(len(i)-1)] #list of values

result =dict(zip(['a','b','c'],values))
```

output:

> {'a': [3.12345, 0.9967], 'b': [5.2345, 0.345, 0.023], 'c': [4.2345]}

Comment: Thanks @HarryPotfleur, it do the job but I'm actually looking for a simpler/generic solution for decoding as this format may changed in the future. I'm already doing a manual parsing which I want to avoid

Comment: Since the sublists vary in size, iteration like this over `a` is required.  This a python list problem, not a numpy array one.